# Как убрать "радугу"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На ноуте стоит убунта. После выхода из спящего режима/гибернации (подъем крышки ноута) наблюдается такой "радужный" эффект. Лечится перезагрузкой. Подскажите, что можно сделать?
З.Ы. дрова на видюху обновлял, если что :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

З.З.Ы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *дрова на видюху обновлял* — вероятно, имеются ввиду проприетарные блобы «отпроизводителя». тогда первое, что стоит опробовать — использовать свободные «драйверы». как показывает практика, с ними проблем несколько меньше.

Comment: я перемещаю окно на основной монитор и радуга стирается (nvidia 340.102-6) - надо покупать новую видеокарту чтоб поставить новые дрова...